# Any easy and free way to install One app Two times in Android

Tags: applications, adb, apk, google-apps

I have seen some other way such as using Pro editor apk. or using root, but I want any other way which is free to install One app two time in my android device.

Thankyou Your answers and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Apps are developer's intellectual property. Modifying them without developer's consent is unethical and possibly illegal too. You can install multiple instances of the same app using Android's user profiles feature.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but i cant find Android's User Profile feature on my device. I think something is related to device owner. (I have Samsung A5 with Android 10)

Comment: You have to create profiles. Try Shelter app. It's open source and free. I've no affiliation. Btw decompiling an app and recompiling after some modifications isn't usually a very tough task if you've some knowledge of Android development (which is off topic here).

Comment: Thanks brother its work. Please answer this into the Answer section so i can accept your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. How about self answering? It's encouraged here. But don't forget to edit your question to reflect what's being answered was asked in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using **Shelter App**. Shelter App created Work Profile on my Android 10.

Shelter is useful for creating an isolated space and utilizing the work profile feature on Android. And in that room, we can install or clone applications.